# Como compartilhar o banco com duas apps android?

Tags: android

Olá, eu tenho 3 apps, uma faz inserção no banco de dados e outra mostra uma lista desses dados (não me perguntem porque essa ideia) e eu precisava que uma terceira mostrasse um count de registros numa tabela desse banco.

Acontece que nessa última o count retorna zerado mesmo que na segunda app mostre itens na lista.

Já me falaram que pode ser que precise compartilhar os contextos entre as apps, mas como fazer isso?

EDIT:
Já deixaram nos comentários que essa não é a melhor opção, então como acessar dados do banco de outra app?

Comment: Teoricamente, todo o conteúdo do context fica no pacote do projeto que tu criou. O porque que te recomendaram isso que é curioso, nunca tive esse problema...

Comment: A sua pergunta também está com falta de contexto:) São 3 apps ou 3 activity? Se você não tem problemas com a segunda não deveria ter com a terceira.

Comment: São 3 apps mesmo. Me deram essa recomendação. Qual seria a melhor alternativa?

Comment: Não posso dizer porque não sei o que pretende fazer. Para que uma app possa aceder ao BD de outra esta tem de implementar um *ContentProvider*

Comment: Num caso simples como esse faça a app, a que tem o BD, implementar um *Service* que disponibilize o número de registos.

Comment: é só um count, não dá pra acessar o mesmo db?

Comment: Detalhe mais a sua pergunta, quais são as apps que utiliza o banco, é apenas uma?

Comment: na primeira frase eu falei:uma faz inserção no banco de dados e outra mostra uma lista desses dados (não me perguntem porque essa ideia) e eu precisava que uma terceira mostrasse um count de registros numa tabela desse banco.

Comment: Como ramaral disse, vc pode usar o ContentProvider para compartilhar os dados que no caso é a quantidade de registros de uma tabela, pode rodar um serviço que faça isso e controle as chamadas da app. Creio que acessar o BD diretamente através de uma terceira app é mais complexo, para falar verdade não sei se é possível fazer isso.

Comment: Aqui vc pode ver como utilizar o [ContentProvider](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk_content-providers--mobile-5549), e como utilizar o [service](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: O BD é privado à app que o criou, por isso, que eu saiba, não é possível outra app acedê-la a não ser através da primeira, via um *Service* ou *ContentProvider*. Você diz que tem uma segunda app. que mostra uma lista, como está fazendo isso?

Comment: eu estou usando um adapter normal e pegando os dados. Na verdade, estou mexendo em apps que outra pessoa fez

Comment: Você está a confundir activity com app. Julgo que o que você tem é uma app com duas *activities* com `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>` Poste o *AndroidManifest.xml*

Comment: Consegui aqui. Agora as três aplicações acessam o mesmo banco de dados, e não, não usei o Content Provider, foi conexão direta.

Comment: @MayogaX se possível poste a sua solução como resposta. Além de ser [algo recomendado](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/422/responder-sua-pr%C3%B3pria-pergunta) pode ajudar outros com o mesmo problema que você passou.